# Rail: Why do I get this bad argument expecred URI object or URI string error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, uri, mailer

application_mailer.rb - asys_delivery

```
def asys_delivery
  mail.delivery_method.settings = Rails.application.secrets.asys_smtp
end
```

asys_symtp contains setting like port, domain, user_name etc.

internal_mailer.rb

```
class InternalMailer < ApplicationMailer
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  after_action :asys_delivery, only: %i[send_ops]

  def send_ops
    mail(from: 'my_mail@gmail.com',
      to: 'my_mail2@gmail.com',
      subject: params[:subject]
    )
  end
end
```

When I try to call the method using this code

`InternalMailer.with(subject: "This is test subject").send_ops.deliver_now`

I got this error

```
2.6.3 :003 > InternalMailer.with(subject: "This is test subject").send_ops.deliver_now
  Rendering internal_mailer/send_ops.html within layouts/mailer
  Rendered internal_mailer/send_ops.html within layouts/mailer (0.3ms)
InternalMailer#send_ops: processed outbound mail in 4.4ms
Sent mail to my_mail2@gmail.com (2.2ms)
Date: Mon, 28 Jun 2021 15:06:14 +0700
From: app.auditsystem@nutrifood.co.id
To: my_mail2@gmail.com
Message-ID: <60d982f6de3e1_779d2aff68ea997033946@LAPTOP-P2N1ECET.mail>
Subject: This is test subject
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style>
      /* Email styles need to be inline */
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= @custom.html_safe %>
  </body>
</html>

Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):3
ArgumentError (bad argument (expected URI object or URI string))
2.6.3 :004 >
```

Also, I'm using mailpy gem

Edit:
Now that I write this, I'm wondering do set smtp setting still required when I use mailpy instead of smtp?

Comment: Can you update your question with the code for `asys_delivery`? Also, please don't use screenshots of code or error messages. It makes it really hard to reproduce issues, search on them later, etc. Just paste in the relevant code and text into the question (and format it).

Comment: Got it, sorry for the conveniences. Already edited the question

Comment: If you haven’t already tried it, your best bet is to remove the after_action and see if the error goes away, and check the values in your secrets file.

Comment: Sorry for late response, yes, removing that code fix the bug. I was a bit hesitant before as I'm not the one who create the project. Thanks man